# Getting ERROR org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule - Unable to build KieBaseModel:defaultKieBase

Tags: java, maven, drools, kie

I am running into this Error while executing my drools project. It's a maven project for a CEP Use-case and the pom.xml does not have any erors. I have attached my kmodule.xml and java code to get my KieSession instance. Can someone tell me what mistake am I making?

Also, getting this error: Unable to resolve ObjectType 'System.out.println' when my drl is executed.

### kmodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">

</kmodule>
```

### Java code sample:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

 KieContainer kieContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
 KieBaseConfiguration config = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();
 config.setOption( EventProcessingOption.STREAM );

 KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.newKieBase( config );

 kSession = kieBase.newKieSession();
```

### Drl file:

```
rule "test pending cart item"
no-loop
when
//conditions
System.out.println("\nPrint Pending Items Rule");
$cart : CartObj( $status == "pending")

then
//actions

end
```

### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.org.testdemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>testdemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20150729</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
            <artifactId>mqtt-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you meant to write

```
rule "test pending cart item"
when
    //conditions
    $cart : CartObj( $status == "pending")
then
    //actions
    System.out.println("\nPrint Pending Items Rule");
end
```

A void method call doing some output is not fit to be part of a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You must to spesificate the kbase and ksession (in your kmoudle.xmkl), and use this to create a session and fire you rules.